# Excel/VBA: change roundness of a rounded rectangle in vba/excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to figure out how to change the roundness of a rounded rectangle shape in Excel using VBA.

I started out by creating the rounded rectangle, but at this point I'm not sure what to do next.

```
Set roundedRec = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 10, 10, 200, 40)
```

I've googled for `vba shapes roundness rounded`, `excel vba rounded rectangle corner radius` and other similar phrases, but haven't found anything terribly instructive or helpful.  I'm beginning to think I can't change this property via visual basic, though I can do it through Excel's GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled `msoShapeRoundedRectangle radius`, and the first [link](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00968.htm) had an example:

```
With oSh
    oSh.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
    .Adjustments(1) = sngRounding
End With
```